# jQuery File Upload - My install's showing all files on server, etc

Tags: jquery, file, upload

I'm hoping someone familiar with [**jQuery File Upload**](http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/) can lend a hand with three issues.

1. I installed it, and unlike their website's demo page (index.html), [**mine**](http://westlandprintworks.com/jquery-file-upload/) shows all the files in the server's "server/php/files" directory - not only those just uploaded on the form submission.  I need users to upload their files, and not see everyone else's uploads.
2. When files are initially added to the queue, it shows the proper filenames, but after "Start upload" is hit and they're actually sent, it names the files "(1)", "(1) (1)", and so on.
3. I want to remove this demo's client and server side previews & thumbnails.  (Some users will be uploading images several hundred megabytes large, and I don't want either system trying to process those.)

(BTW, the demo page says uploaded files are deleted automatically after 5 minutes, which doesn't seem to be the case with their demo's PHP backend.  That's great - I don't want files automatically deleted.)

P.S. If it's not asking too much, I just noticed that my demo's index.html still has action="//jquery-file-upload.appspot.com/" in the form, yet is writing the files to my server, and am confused.

Comment: CentOS 5.8.  apache 2.2.3-65.  php 5.1.6-39.  php-pecl-json 1.2.1-4 (since wasn't built in back on php 5.1, and is needed by their backend PHP script).

Comment: When you click on the file upload "Browse" button, it shows the files on your computer, not files on the server.

Comment: Sorry, I may not have been clear.  Once you browse your computer and add files, it creates a zebra styled list of the files, each with its own start and cancel buttons.  On my install, on a fresh load of the page, even in a browser with cleared cache/cookies, it's not starting the page with no list -- it's showing everything in the server's directory.  If you visit the "mine" link, unless it's checking for IP address, you'll see several files already there.

Comment: @user1902689 I am have this issue too, is it resolved for you?

Comment: @hmd - No, a few weeks after running into this, I gave up on the project.  Sorry to hear you're having this too, but I'm glad this question came back to me.  I'll have to give it another shot soon.  I'll especially have to try Oleksii and Tim's answers, and see if they help.

Comment: @user1902689 I am working on it and might have a solution. Will share if you need it. The solution lies in the fact that you have to modify get() function so it retrieves data from the database rather than the directory. Thx for responding.

Answer (score 0):

If you're gonna have this with a login system, have it create a folder with their unique ID and upload the file there.  Otherwise you're probably gonna need to do some fancy naming convention and only display files matching those names.

Comment: Someday I plan on having a login system, but for now I wanted a way for people to be able to upload files, but not see what's been uploaded out of that form submission.  Basically a black hole anyone can send files into.

Answer (score 0):

## 1:

Edit the main index.php file and remove the following:

```
 <tr class="template-download fade">
  {% if (file.error) { %}
  <td></td>
  <td class="name"><span>{%=file.name%}</span></td>
  <td class="size"><span>{%=o.formatFileSize(file.size)%}</span></td>
  <td class="error" colspan="2"><span class="label label-important">Error</span> {%=file.error%}</td>
  {% } else { %}
  <td class="preview">{% if (file.thumbnail_url) { %}
    <a href="{%=file.url%}" title="{%=file.name%}" data-gallery="gallery" download="{%=file.name%}"><img src="{%=file.thumbnail_url%}"></a>
    {% } %}</td>
  <td class="name">
    <a href="{%=file.url%}" title="{%=file.name%}" data-gallery="{%=file.thumbnail_url&&'gallery'%}" download="{%=file.name%}">{%=file.name%}</a>
  </td>
  <td class="size"><span>{%=o.formatFileSize(file.size)%}</span></td>
  <td colspan="2"></td>
  {% } %}
  <td class="delete">
    <button class="btn btn-danger" data-type="{%=file.delete_type%}" data-url="{%=file.delete_url%}"{% if (file.delete_with_credentials) { %} data-xhr-fields='{"withCredentials":true}'{% } %}>
            <i class="icon-trash icon-white"></i>
      <span>Delete</span>
    </button>
    <input type="checkbox" name="delete" value="1">
  </td>
</tr>
```

## 2

The (1) naming is done if there already exists a file with the same name.

## 3

The solution from #1 will solve this also.

The 5 min deletion is only with the app running on their server.

The form action is not needed if all you are doing is accepting files. You can remove it.

Comment: How would you modify the file upload so that it does not show files uploaded by other users, but does show the files just uploaded. (Uploaded files do not disappear immediately after uploading.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about all of your questions, but the first issue (separation files for different users) is solved with `user_dirs` setting of `UploadHandler` class. In index.php you make it like this:

```
<?php
// ...
$upload_handler = new UploadHandler(array(
    'user_dirs' => true
));
```

For more details see this page: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/PHP-user-directories.